# Spark hangs on union with zero running task

Tags: scala, apache-spark, union, distributed

I have two records of type RDD[T]

```
For example:
val a: RDD[Integer] = ....
val b: RDD[Integer] = ...
when I perform
val z = a.union(b)
println(z)
```

I find the spark hangs for ever

> [Stage 23:=============================>                            (1
>   + 0) / 2]

Not sure why it shows 0 running tasks.

**Environment:**

Spark 1.6

Scala 2.11.6

Total records in a and b is 10 records each. It is a small file.

Did anyone came across this case where running task is zero and the spark hangs and never ends.

Comment: If you can reproduce it, could you do a thread dump and post it here?

Comment: are you running out of resource ? Which mode you are running spark ? 
If local start using --master local[*], if yarn make sure you have containers(resource) available.

Comment: If both transformations are applied to the same RDD, Use `.cache()` prior to invoking them.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov no both are different RDD. And it freeze when it hits a keyBy. 
Summary Metrics

No tasks have started yet
Tasks

No tasks have started yet
I did transformation of RDD using combineByKey and I see this behavior after that.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I tried use .cache() with an action like a.cache().count() and then do the union. In this case it worked. Not sure why? any theory behind why this is behaving like this?  I am trying to avoid as many action in my main source code and this would be a performance issue. Trying to see if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: Did you find any root cause for this? I am getting a hung spark job on union as well.

Comment: The above solution worked for me as well. Adding a cache in the right place.

Comment: Does anybody find the root cause, why this is happening with the union?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently setting

```
--conf spark.driver.host=127.0.0.1
```

solved the problem for me.

Let's thanks [Melitta Dragaschnig](https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@spark.apache.org/msg295188.html) & [rrusso2007](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16087)

Edit: Just wanted to mention that I was facing this problem when doing a union between 2 DataFrames from which one was created by reading from Cassandra (using the DataStax Spark Cassandra Connector)